# How would I target this tag in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, css-selectors, puppeteer

I was doing an automation fun project and I choose this website https://agoodmovietowatch.com/  this is a single-page website so to target the sign-up link I inspect and find that this sign-up link is not a

```
<a>
```

tag but an

```
<h6>
```

tag and I cant able to target it, I tried all combinations to select it every class it contains but failed.
If someone knows so tell me, please.

here is my code :

```
await page.waitForSelector("div.tss-1xh7ius-secondaryLinksContainer.MuiBox-root.mui-0 div.text_container__2Nx5h.tss-w9yc2n-secondaryLink.MuiBox-root.mui-0");

await page.click("div.tss-1xh7ius-secondaryLinksContainer.MuiBox-root.mui-0 div.text_container__2Nx5h.tss-w9yc2n-secondaryLink.MuiBox-root.mui-0");
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

```
const signUpBtn = await page.$(".tss-1xh7ius-secondaryLinksContainer > div")
await signUpBtn.click()
```

And to select "the very best", you can use:

```
await page.click(".tss-1ch6vtq-buttonsContainer :first-child")
```

If you want to learn more about CSS selectors, I recommend checking out this nice and funny teaching website: [CSS Diner](https://flukeout.github.io/)

Comment: Thanks, man it works. I appreciate it

Comment: can you tell me one more solution. I can't able to target on same page "the very best" tag man how i tried all selectors but cant please help me on this